# How to use F1 Help without keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, highlighting a keyword and pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> will take you to the relevant help page documentation about it.

How can I do this if I don't have an F1 key? Is there a menu item or ribbon button or different key press I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a toolbar button for "F1 Help" *by default* but you can customize your toolbar to add one. Click the "Add or Remove Buttons" icon at the right of your main toolbar:

[image]

Then, from the second pop-up menu you get from that small drop-down, select the "Customize..." command. In the pop-up dialogue box that follows, select the "Commands" tab and click the "Add Command" button …

[image]

Finally, in the "Add Command" dialogue-box, select the "Help" category in the left-hand pane and scroll down the right-hand pane until you see the "F1 Help" button, select that and click OK …

[image]

You will now have a new button on your toolbar (the blue disk with a `?` in it) that will execute F1 Help when you click it:

[image]

(The process outlined here, and the images given, are for Visual Studio 2022; however, VS-2019 has a very similar workflow to achieve the same result.)